# "attribute 5 has wrong type" when inserting jsonb with ON CONFLICT into a postgres view?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

I have a roles table that looks like this:

```
    Table "public.roles"
     Column      |  Type   |                     Modifiers
-----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer | not null default nextval('roles_id_seq'::regclass)
 name            | text    | not null
 organization_id | integer |
 is_system       | boolean | default false
 definition      | jsonb   | default '{}'::jsonb
Indexes:
    "roles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "roles_name_organization_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (name, organization_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "roles_organization_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (organization_id) REFERENCES organizations(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "role_roles" CONSTRAINT "role_roles_subject_role_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (subject_role_id) REFERENCES roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "role_roles" CONSTRAINT "role_roles_target_role_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (target_role_id) REFERENCES roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "user_roles" CONSTRAINT "user_roles_role_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    add_pg_role_on_add BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON roles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_pg_role_on_add()
    delete_pg_role_on_delete BEFORE DELETE ON roles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_pg_role_on_delete()
```

And a view "api"."roles" that looks like

```
CREATE VIEW api.roles AS SELECT * FROM roles WHERE organization_id IN (select * from organization_ids()) OR is_superuser();
```

Where organization_ids is a function that returns the organizations that user is a member of.

When I do an insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO "api"."roles" ("id", "name", "organization_id", "definition") VALUES (DEFAULT, 'coder', 289, '{}'::jsonb)
ON CONFLICT ("name", "organization_id")
  DO UPDATE SET "name" = EXCLUDED."name", "definition" = EXCLUDED."definition",
    "organization_id"  = EXCLUDED."organization_id";
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  attribute 5 has wrong type
DETAIL:  Table has type integer, but query expects jsonb.
```

I've googled around, and I can't really get what it is trying to tell me is wrong with this insert. If I remove the `EXCLUDED.definition` bit, the query works. It doesn't seem to depend on the actual `definition` value that is being inserted, but rather that I'm doing an update with the definition column. I'm also able to update the definition column on records in this view using the `UPDATE` command. It seems to just be the upsert that is busted.

Does anyone know what is causing this, or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!